# Front camera is not opening every time in Pop over controller in iPad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

In my iPad app i am trying to open Front facing camera in a UIPopOverController.It is behaving in strange behavior.When i first time click on button to open camera,it open front camera and second time it open rear camera again same repeat.once front camera and second time rear camera.While i have also set front camera as a camera device.Here is my code,Please help.

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.allowsEditing = YES;
    [imagePickerController setCameraCaptureMode:UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModePhoto];
    [imagePickerController setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];

 UIPopoverController *popoverController=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imagePickerController];
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:((UIButton *)sender).bounds inView:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer my self. I was not releasing imagePickerController.
After releasing it i get every time front camera. ;)